# should QA do their testing twice, once on staging and then again on prod?

Tags: testing, deployment, qa, production, build-system

the QA team should ideally do their testing on an environment that almost exactly matches the prod env (to minimize uncaught bugs that arise due to setting differences).

If that's true, does the QA team typically do the testing again on prod post deployment in the googles and amazons out there? If the answer is yes that sounds redundant.. but also how can they not test production?

Comment: Do you care if the code actually runs in the production environment? How certain are you that staging and production are identical?

Comment: They at least monitor error rates and performance on all their servers and check for increases or differences between different versions running at the same time.

Comment: See https://www.quora.com/How-is-it-to-be-a-QA-at-Google-How-do-they-balance-manual-and-automation-testing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends what you're doing, but often you can't test in production because the system is now attached to real resources. In the case of Amazon, would you run a real order with a real credit card and wait for the book to arrive? You often need to be careful about putting test data into a production system.

Once it's gone live, you're dependent on your monitoring systems to give you early warnings of bugs. Sudden drop in completed orders? Better roll back the update then go digging in the logs to find out what happened.

(Arguably what SpaceX have been doing is "testing in production" with their rocket recovery system: it's not really cost feasible to do dummy launches, so they launch with the real payload and then see if the system can manage to land the rocket.)

Comment: I would be surprised if amazon didn't have people/scripts ordering stuff in the live system as a quality assurance measure. That would include receiving the packets to test the packaging, postage etc. The cost of this is minimal. But it wouldn't be test data.

Comment: Indeed, your Amazon example is flawed. Not only, like Bent explained, a valid purchase has a tiny cost compared to, say, the cost of running a test server or a month wage of a tester, but it is also possible to test the purchasing process and then cancel the order, like any legitimate user could do.

Comment: When I worked on a large e-commerce web site, we had dummy credit card numbers we could use on the production system. The system was programmed to accept the orders, but they would be cancelled as soon as they were processed.

Comment: @TMN ...unless that cancellation code is buggy :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't test in production because you won't find anything you don't find in a proper test environment. Maybe some kind of quick check if deployment went ok, but this is not a big part of testing.

First you test your code (unit test). 
Then you test your code in the whole application (integration test). 
Then you test your code in the whole system landscape (system test).

All further testing is done by people who don't gain anything from finding or reporting bugs, which - when you think about it - sucks for the quality of the product.

Answer (score 0):

"Testing" isn't a single thing and it's not something that is only done once either. From requirement to deployment, code should go through many levels of testing:

1. When the code is built and checked in, unit and integration tests should run,
2. As part of any task, a tester should be both checking the implementation against requirements and testing that the feature works in a sane and usable fashion,
3. Features should be reviewed by the requester prior to production to check what they asked for is what they wanted,
4. Various types of user, acceptance and regression testing are likely to be run prior to release,
5. Even when released, it's still possible to then use the customers to do A/B testing and allow them to report bugs.

The whole thing forms the quality control (QC) around a piece of code. Arguing "should testing be done once or twice" misses the extent to which code is actually tested (in a good environment).

Oh and please don't call it "QA". Software testing can never cover 100% of all possible combinations of user/data interaction and program flow. So it's not possible to offer assurance that code is fit for purpose. All you can do is quality control through "sample testing".

Comment: This doesn't answer the question if tests which were done in staging should be performed once again in production.

Comment: @MainMa, oh, it does answer it. I clearly didn't answer it very clearly though. In staging, QC is typically done via UAT, SIT, regression testing and the like. In production, QC involves smoke testing, A/B testing, bug reporting and so forth. So, no, the same tests should not be run in both.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally Yes, QA should test the live system. Otherwise, you still test the live system, you just get your customers to do it instead.

The real question is how to achieve this when you have stateful applications. ie. how do i test my DeleteAllOrders button (extreme example), without actually deleting all the orders?

Normally this is achieved by having a test environment, but as you have noticed this is flawed. There is no guarantee that something which works in the test env will work in live. Plus, inevitably you end up with dozens of test environments for all the different features or teams and it becomes very hard to test whether everything will work together nicely on the day.

A second approach is to have a subset of tests that you run on live, 'smoke tests' these allow you to test the easy things. "Place a test order, but cancel it before we get charged", etc. but again, it's not perfect.

**To fully test your live system you need to program your system with testability in mind.**

If you create a Delete**All**Orders button, you need to be thinking 'ok how will I test this?' maybe I should add an UndeleteAllTheOrdersIjustDeleted button as well!

If some function of a system is rarely done, or hard to test it doesn't equate with that function being unimportant.

Best practice is to test your live system all the time. If a problem develops you want to know about it straight away.

For example, if you have an eCommerce site you would constantly be placing dummy orders to ensure that you site is up and selling goods. If the dummy orders start failing you want to know right away, not have to wait for a customer to call your helpline.

Comment: The goal of smoke tests is somehow different: to ensure that the new revision didn't f*** up so much that the application is no longer usable. For instance, on an e-commerce website, it may consist of going to the home page, searching for a product and actually purchasing it, then cancelling the order before it's shipped. While smoke tests can technically run in production and ensure that the production is not screwed up, this is not enough to be alerted when production-related regressions are introduced. One should also have a bunch of functional tests for that.

Comment: About your `DeleteAllOrders` example, there is actually nothing simpler. Using the same example of an e-commerce website, the test suite can register an account, perform several orders, and then cancel/delete all of them—since this is scoped to the user, and the user is a test one, the consequences are harmless (unless there is a regression with the `where user =` clause being mistakenly removed.) Of course, things are different for *administrative* actions such as `RemoveAllUsers`. But do we really need to test those in production, after doing the same tests in staging?

Comment: i meant delete**ALL**orders ie in the universe all

Comment: my point is you always test in production whether you like it or not. you can only choose who tests it first. you or your customer

Comment: @Ewan: Stuff like deleteALLorders shouldn't be in code at all.  When something that dangerous needs to be done, it's done as a one-off task.  It should be *difficult* to do crazy stuff.

Comment: @Brian Launching nuclear missiles should also be hard. Doesn't make it less important to test the function works!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes testing should be done twice in staging and production environments.

The biggest factor in testing staging is making sure new features work as expected and that existing features aren't broken.  This testing should ideally be thorough at unit and functional levels and usually takes some time to run.

The biggest factor in testing production is making sure that existing functionality is not broken using the actual machines, networks, configurations, etc. that are serving up the software.  These are often quick 'sanity' or 'smoke' tests that can run very quickly and ensure that the main 'happy' path is still working correctly.

I have also learned that testing in either staging or production environments is often too late to add quality in todays, mostly Agile, environments.  At that point the code has been written and is less malleable to changes (confession: I am former developer).  It is better to focus on test plans and design before any code is written and then to focus on test code before the application code is written so that the tests can guide the code in a TDD/BDD fashion with testing being done in the **local** and **ci** environments.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, testing in a staged environment and not testing again on prod often results in bugs being released into prod. My organization tracks very closely production issues that are the result of a recent change, and then looks closely at the release process followed to find the breakdown.

Human error often leads to the stage environment not being the exact mirror of the prod environment. Or, all of the systems that are upstream and downstream aren't also replicated in stage. Or, the stage environment did not have the full volume of data that flows through the prod system.

Isn't there an old saying that goes something like "no one has ever been fired for performing too much diligence, but plenty for not applying enough?" If there isn't, there should be.

In reality, you can't test everything 100% else your product would never get released into use, and figuring out where to draw the line is not easy.

Comment: *"not testing again on prod"*: again? Don't you think the problem is the gap (in configuration, topology or hardware) between staging and production environments? *"Human error often leads to the stage environment not being the exact mirror of the prod environment."*: this explains everything. Staging and production servers should be deployed in an automated way. Once you solve this, you won't need to barely repeat tests (and waste twice the time).

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of QA is to make sure that the end product meets the client requirements and application is stable enough to deploy. so Even if QA environments mimic production environments, we could have some Issues during deployments like some small missing configuration or server Issues, or even some new bugs due to missing data!!

I worked with several companies that uses different QA strategies, some of them never test production and Others had special team to test production and assure that everything is perfect.

From my experience, there's no "redundant" QA actions!! it's always depends on the managers vision and the project size and milestones.

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes. But at this point It would be good to have automated Integration, functional and performance tests and have'em executing frequently. That's the purpose of systems like Continous Integration whos QA can relay on.  At this point I would search about *Continous Delivery* and *Continous Testing*.

The ideal escenario is the one where everything has been tested in *test*, *int* and *pre*. Finally QA say OK/KO to the release. But the code has been stressed all over *staging* envs before to run in production. But we know that ideal scenarios are quite uncommon in software engineery.

The common scenario to me is the one where software is not mine (I'm the provider), to perform any operative in production should be because it has been *dealed* and it appears in the contract.

So customer is going to test pro manually! But they will with a test plan written by me or my QA team (provider)

As you see, to perform test in Pro sometimes is a political decition. In other scenarios depends on your strategy at delivery management.